# Filtering a dataframe column for rows that contain certain text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains certain columns, one of which is Position and another one is Years of Service. Based on these, I want to create a new column 'Life Cover'. I have created this function for that.

```
def LifeCover(row):
if row['Years of Service']>5:
    val = 8
elif row['Years of Service']>2 and row['Position'] in ['Associate', 'Director', 'Director of Facilities Management', 'Director of Promise', 'Director, Head of Facilities Management']:
    val = 8
elif row['Years of Service']>2 and row['Position'] not in ['Associate', 'Director', 'Director of Facilities Management', 'Director of Promise', 'Director, Head of Facilities Management']:
    val = 7
else:
    val = 3
return val

df['Potential Life Cover Level'] = df.apply(LifeCover, axis=1)
```

This works, but I don't like having such a big list of positions, and it turns out the list might need to grow as well, so it is not practical either.

What I need is to include/exclude any position that contains the word Associate or Director or Partner.

I have managed to filter like that:

```
target = ['Associate', 'Director', 'Partner']
dfhigh = df[df['Position'].apply(lambda sentence: any(word in sentence for word in target))]
dflow = df[~df['Position'].apply(lambda sentence: any(word in sentence for word in target))]
```

So I get a dataframe with high positions, and one with low ones.

And then I try to include that in my function:

```
def LifeCover2(row):
if row['Years of Service']>5:
    val = 8
elif row['Years of Service']>2 and row['Position'] in dfhigh['Position']:
    val = 8
elif row['Years of Service']>2 and row['Position'] in dflow['Position']:
    val = 7
else:
    val = 3
return val
```

But for some reason, it only returns values 8 or 3.

I also tried this:

```
def LifeCover2(row):
if row['Years of Service']>5:
    val = 8
elif row['Years of Service']>2 and row['Position'].str.contains('Associate|Director|Partner'):
    val = 8
elif row['Years of Service']>2 and (~row['Position'].str.contains('Associate|Director|Partner')):
    val = 7
else:
    val = 3
return val
```

which returns a AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 69')

Comment: Are you sure that there are rows that fulfill the criteria for value 7 ?

Comment: No, this is what I am trying to understand, but I am stuck - also not very experienced with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str.contains` method is a vectorized string operation ( [see here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.10-working-with-strings.html)). This means that it is a method for for pandas Series and not string types. When you use `df.apply`, pandas tries to use `str.contains` for each element of the column you selected instead of doing it at the Series level.

I would suggest the following approach:

```
df['LifeCover2'] = 3

df['LifeCover2'] = np.where(df['Years of Service']>5, 8, df['LifeCover2'])

df['LifeCover2'] = np.where((df['Years of Service']>2) & 
                        (df['Position'].str.contains('Associate|Director|Partner')), 8, df['LifeCover2'])

df['LifeCover2'] = np.where((df['Years of Service']>2) & 
                        (~df['Position'].str.contains('Associate|Director|Partner')), 7, df['LifeCover2'])
```